# Getting the RecurringMaster ID through FindItem SOAP Call

Tags: c++, soap, exchangewebservices

I am making a soap call to exchange to get all the recurring meetings (C++).

So initially when I do a FindItem request I get back all the appointments in the specified time in Calendar View (Start and End Times).

But for recurring using the same call can I get the master recurring ID for the Item ID whichever I have received.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:GetItem>
         <mes:ItemShape>
            <typ:BaseShape>IdOnly</typ:BaseShape>
            <typ:AdditionalProperties>
              <!-- We only query the properties that we need -->
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" /> <!-- Leave for debugging purposes -->
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Categories" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DateTimeCreated" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:LastModifiedTime" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Sensitivity" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ItemClass" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Start" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:End" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:CalendarItemType" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:IsRecurring" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Recurrence" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:FirstOccurrence" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:LastOccurrence" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:ModifiedOccurrences" />
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:DeletedOccurrences" />
            </typ:AdditionalProperties>
         </mes:ItemShape>
         <mes:ItemIds>
            <typ:RecurringMasterItemId OccurrenceId="AAMk[snip]A=="/>
         </mes:ItemIds>
      </mes:GetItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The OccurrenceID is the ItemID that you got for the occurrence through FindItem.